# Готовность других задач в asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, асинхронность, asyncio

Я начал изучать асинхронную разработку в Python 3 и столкнулся с такой дилеммой:

Допустим, у меня есть задачи, и внутри я проверяю, что если эта задача будет выполнятся "долго", то я её "откладываю" (передаю управление следующей корутине в событийном цикле):

```
import asyncio
import time


async def calculate(value):
    if value > 10000:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.0001)
    data = value ** value
    print('Calculated {}'.format(value))
    return data


async def main():
    task_1 = calculate(98230)
    task_2 = calculate(16780)
    task_3 = calculate(656)
    task_4 = calculate(1078)
    tasks_list = [task_1, task_2, task_3, task_4]
    finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait(tasks_list, loop=loop, return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED)
    for unfinished_task in unfinished:
        unfinished_task.cancel()
    return finished


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    result = loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
    print('Exec time: ' + str(time.time() - start))
```

И соответственно вопрос, как я могу проверить, "готовы" ли другие задачи, что бы начать вычисления для текущей, **например** так:

```
async def calculate(value):
    if value > 10000:
        while not loop.other_tasks_done():
            await asyncio.sleep(0.0001)
    data = value ** value
    print('Calculated {}'.format(value))
    return data
```

Comment: Не знаю, просто, для примера ли это или нет, но сразу же замечу, что asyncio не предназначен для работы с тяжёлыми вычислениями. Кстати, `await asyncio.sleep(0)` тоже передаёт управление другим корутинам

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. По коду, да, это скорее для примера, некая "имитация" долгого ответа.

Comment: семафор поставь. Он не даст запустить новых тасков с таким же семафором

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очередь из задач имеет  смысл строить если они не очень асинхронные, блокируют какие-то ресурсы (пропускную способность сети, память, прерывания или диск).

Если брать математику вроде `data = value ** value`, то тут задача синхронна и блокирует проц.
В таком случае тяжелые задания лучше отправлять в `*Executor`. С обычными задачами всё просто, а вот асинхронные придется выполнять в отдельном `event loop`.

```
def run(corofn, *args):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    try:
        coro = corofn(*args)
        return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    finally:
        loop.close()

async def calculate(value):
    ...


executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)

tasks_list = []
for value in values:
   tasks_list.append(loop.run_in_executor(executor, run, calculate, value))

finished, unfinished = await asyncio.wait(tasks_list, ...
```

В примере можно убрать `run` если в `calculate` нет асинхронных вызовов. `max_workers` означает что задачи будут выполняться по 3.

Другой подход это приостановить задачи перед выполнением. Для этого есть [семафоры](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore). Он больше подходит для работы с сетью и прочим вводом-выводом, но также хорошо справится с задачами на процессор. С памятью же надо поработать вручную перед отпусканием семафора.

Создаем `sema = asyncio.Semaphore(3)`

В функцию добавляешь `acquire` и `release`

```
async def calculate(sema, value):
    await sema.acquire()
    if value > 10000:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.0001)
    data = value ** value
    sema.release()
    print('Calculated {}'.format(value))
    return data
```

Таски будут залоченны пока не выполнятся первые 3.

Comment: Благодарю за расширенный ответ!